# Phonegap record video for maximum 15 seconds

Tags: android, ios, video, cordova

I am creating an application in which user has to record video not more that 15 seconds. How to check duration while capturing video in phonegap. User should not record video more than 15 seconds.

I dont want to use the below code.

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles) {
            mediaFiles[0].getFormatData(function(data) {
                if(data.duration > 15) {
                    alert('Your video is longer than the allowed 30 seconds.');
                }
            });
    }, function(error) { alert('An error occured'); }, null);
```

This checks duration after capturing video. 
Is it possible to stop recording video once user reach limit of 15 second.

Answer (score 0):

In cordova have many option to handle this.....

so you need set

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureVideoSuccess, captureErrorVideo, { 
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URL,duration:15});
```

duration take in seconds....When camera reached 15 seconds of video its automatically closed and call **captureVideoSuccess**. now you write your logic here..........

[Check this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions)

Comment: The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths cannot be limited programmatically. written on the link which you sent.

Comment: Recording lengths cannot be limited programmatically you are right.... but duration is maximum size of video length. so its working all android device perfectly for me

Comment: this feature is not supported for iOS so any idea about making it work on iOS. currently i am getting error code 3 unfortunately gallery has stopped on android.

Comment: i am also working with ios and  android man... its working fine for me .....your cordova version?

Comment: current 3.4.0 i havent tested on ios yet. any idea why i was getting the error on android .?

Answer (score 0):

This has been posted long time ago, but I'll answer this anyway since I had similiar problem (but with audio). What you could do on Android is to set timeout with function that will stop recording.
Here's my code for audio recording with timeout after 10 seconds:

```
var src = "tmprecording.amr";
        mediaRec = new Media(src, function() { // success
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
        }, function(err) { //error
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
        });
//Record audio
mediaRec.startRecord();
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        //Here's your recording stop
        mediaRec.stopRecord();
        mediaRec.release();
        mediaRec = null;
    }, 10000);
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yea i tried set time out functions too But on few devices code works fine. But few devices it does not even work at all.! So that was the main issue.. Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: What do you mean by on few it works on few it doesnt, can you be more specific?

Comment: I was testing on galaxy grand 2 it worked everytime. But on galaxy nexus , micromax and sony xperia it worked once a while. Maim reason was it get stuck in process some where down the line and app gets restarted due to that.

Comment: Have you released your media / set it to null / destroyed when not needed?

Comment: Well even before doing that it got stuck. Its hard to explain over text.